# Регулярное выражение php не определяет конец строки или слова

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не работает такое выражение, если в `$text` искомое слово `$name` стоит в конце строки:

```
preg_match('~[\b\s\\-]?'.$name.'[\b\s\-]~iu', $text, $t)
```

`$name` - искомое слово, `$text` - где ищем.

Причем такие варианты регулярных выражений тоже не срабатывают:

```
preg_match('~[\b\s\\-\A]?'.$name.'[\b\s\\-\Z]~iu', $text, $t)
preg_match('~[\b\s\\-^]?'.$name.'[\b\s\\-$]~iu', $text, $t)
```

Срабатывает только если в конце добавить `?`, но мне это не нужно, т.к. обязательным условием является наличие: пробела, тире, конца слова или строки.

Answer (score 2):

Внутри символьного класса нет возможности объявить шаблоны нулевой длины. `[\b]` находит символ BACKSPACE, `\x08`.

Используйте подмаски и блоки предварительного просмотра:

```
preg_match('~(?<=\b|[\s-])'.$name.'(?=\b|[\s-])~iu', $text, $t)
```

Блок предварительного просмотра назад `(?<=\b|[\s-])` проверяет на начало слова или наличие пробельного символа или дефиса прямо перед `$name`, а блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?=\b|[\s-])` осуществляет проверку на конец слова или пробельный символ либо дефис сразу после.

Если в `$name` могут быть символы, которые являются специальными символами в регулярных выражениях, рекомендуется добавить `preg_quote`:

```
preg_match('~(?<=\b|[\s-])' . preg_quote($name, '~') . '(?=\b|[\s-])~iu', $text, $t)
```

Comment: К сожалению такая конструкция не работает. Работает preg_match('~(\b|\s|\-)?' . preg_quote($name) . '(\b|\s|\-|\Z|$)~iu', $text, $t)

Comment: [У меня всё прекрасно работает](https://regex101.com/r/iIcfvH/1). Нет смысла указывать `\Z` и  `$`, `$` нахдит ту же позицию, что и `\Z`. Шаблон `(\b|\s|\-)?` необязателен, значит, не имеет смысла в данном случае (он ничем не ограничивает совпадение). Экранирование `-` необязательно, если дефис находится вне символьного класса.

Comment: В таком варианте - нет :) [https://regex101.com/r/iIcfvH/2]

Comment: @sergvm `"` не является буквой, цифрой или `_`, между ним и концом слова нет "границы слова". Определитесь с тем, что для вас является "словом", потом уж думайте о шаблоне. Если для вас слово - это то, что между пробелов, используйте `'~(?<!\S)' . preg_quote($name, '~') . '(?!\S)~iu'`.

Comment: Смысл в том, что $name - это определенные характеристики, ищутся в $text. Причем $name может как содержаться в $text, так и полностью с ним совпадать. Одно ограничение $name не может содержаться в сплошном "слове", т.е. должно быть ограничено пробелами, границами слова, тире, началом или концом строки. При этом в характеристиках($name) могут содержаться " (дюйм), '.' (десятичная точка), '-' (интервал значений).

Comment: @sergvm Так как ничего этого не указано в вопросе, мой ответ верен: единственная проблема — это использование `\b` в символьном классе.

Comment: Не оспариваю ваш ответ. Мне нужно было получить ответ почему моя изначальная конструкция не работает. Частично я его получил. Спасибо.